# How to install nvidia transfer learning toolkit in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, nvidia

I tried with solutions available online but none worked. Nvidia TLT is using docker image so is it possible in colab?

```
docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/tlt-streamanalytics:v1.0_py2
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible as of now because Google Colab does not support Docker. I tried running [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10OinT5ZNGtdLLQ9K399jlKgNgidxUbGP) notebook to install Docker.

You can refer to this [Installing Docker on Google Colab](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/299).